# Dynamically create bean

Tags: spring

I have requirement to dynamically create bean, I want to do something like below

context1 in external filesystem

```
<bean id="env" class="java.lang.String">
      <constructor-arg value="dev"/>
 </bean> 
 <import resource="classpath:context2/>"
```

context2 in classpath as below :

```
<bean id="#{env}_config" value="some value here"/>
```

in java  when I try to refer to bean dev_config through context1 application context, it gives exception that dev_config bean not found. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add context namespace (must have spring-context.jar) , and specify scan attribute and specify the package you want to scan for new beans

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="{quulified name for your package}">
</context:component-scan>
```

Each class you want to generate a bean for need to be annotated with @Component

```
       @Component
       public class MyClass
```

Comment: This will not solve my problem. If someone modified application context in context1 and set env to uat, java code should be able to find uat_config bean in application context without any changes.